# is it possible to trigger the npm mirror package sync proactively

Tags: npm, mirror

I am using a npm mirror registry right now, this is my config:

```
registry=https://registry.npmmirror.com/
```

Now I am facing a issue that when I pushed the newest npm package to npmjs official site, the mirror site update has some latency. Sometimes the latency will greater than hours. Is it possible to trigger the package sync immediately when pushed the newest package? Is there any hook or api that will trigger the package sync by myself? or some mechanism that when fetched failed from mirror, try to fetch the package from official site?